# Is my understanding of the Gini plot to detect fat tails correct?

Tags: distributions, kurtosis, gini

I'm trying to reproduce the following plot:

[image]

which was generated on the Danish dataset of fire insurance claims using the `ineq()` function (a wrapper for functions that include calculating the Gini coefficient). This was found on [this lecture](https://youtu.be/eUWlzAQfgFw) and called 'concentration profile'.

> a given sequence of truncated Gini indices, which we call
> Concentration Profile (CP), can be used to characterize losses,
> allowing (1) for the identification of parametric families of
> distributions, and (2) for the observation of features that are not
> immediately available from data, like the actual behavior of risk in
> the tail.

The plot seems to say that the absolute distance between points as you progress to the tails doesn't drop until the end (where there are few data points left), and this invariance in the spread indicates fat tails - not sure about all this.

The code for the plot is

```
library('evir')
library('ineq')
data(danish)
sort_danish = sort(danish)
n=length(danish)
CP=c()
for (i in 1:n) CP[i]=ineq(sort_danish[i:n], type='Gini')

plot(1:n,CP,ylim=c(0,1),pch=19, cex=.3, col=rgb(0, 0, 100, max = 100, alpha = 50))
```

I would assume they use the formula [in here](https://www.statsdirect.com/help/default.htm#nonparametric_methods/gini.htm) for the Gini coefficient:

$$G=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \vert x_i - x_j\vert}{2n^2\bar x}$$

This should be reproduced with:

```
library('evir')
data(danish)

v = sort(danish, decreasing = FALSE)

n = length(danish)

vec <- rep(0,n)
for (i in 1:n){
  mat <- matrix(0, n-i+1 , n-i+1)
  for (j in 1:(n-i+1)){
    mat[j,] <- abs(v[i+j-1] - v[i:n])
  }
  vec[i] <- sum(mat) / (2 * (n-i+1)^2 * mean(mat))
}

plot(vec)
```

if I interpret the Gini calculations properly, but it doesn't, leading me to believe I'm misunderstanding the plot.

Comment: I thought the Gini coefficient was based on double the area between the Lorenz curve and the diagonal.  Whatever your plot shows, it is not a [Lorenz curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_curve)

Comment: @Henry I posted the link on an edit of the question to the lecture where I found the plot, which I was finally able to reproduce without canned functions (see answer). I am not sure what the connection is between this "concentration plot" and the conventional idea behind the Gini coefficient as an area.

Comment: @Henry At least three different measures have been called the Gini coefficient.

Answer (score 4):

Mission accomplished, thanks to [this post](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/16503/36132), which made me see clearly the silly mistake of dividing by the mean of the entire submatrix in the original question. Instead, the mean that is pertinent is of the segment of the tail under consideration in each iteration as in:

```
library('evir')
data(danish)

v = sort(danish, decreasing = FALSE)

n = length(danish)

CP <- rep(0,n)
for (i in 1:n){
  mat <- matrix(0, n-i+1 , n-i+1)
  for (j in 1:(n-i+1)){
    mat[j,] <- abs(v[i+j-1] - v[i:n])
  }
  CP[i] <- sum(mat) / (2 * (n-i+1)^2 * mean(v[i:n]))
}

plot(1:n,CP,ylim=c(0,1),pch=19, cex=.3, col=rgb(0, 0, 100, max = 100, alpha = 50))
```

[image]

The mechanics in the code can be appreciated by printing the sub-matrices in each iteration with a short random vector:

```
set.seed(0)

v = round(runif(3,2,35))
v
n = length(v)

CP <- rep(0,n)
for (i in 1:n){
  mat <- matrix(0, n-i+1 , n-i+1)
  for (j in 1:(n-i+1)){
    mat[j,] <- abs(v[i+j-1] - v[i:n])
    print(mat)
  }
  CP[i] <- sum(mat) / (2 * (n-i+1)^2 * mean(v[i:n]))
  print(CP)
}
```

with output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0   21   18
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0   21   18
[2,]   21    0    3
[3,]    0    0    0
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0   21   18
[2,]   21    0    3
[3,]   18    3    0
[1] 0.245614 0.000000 0.000000
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    3
[2,]    0    0
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    3
[2,]    3    0
[1] 0.245614 0.060000 0.000000
     [,1]
[1,]    0
[1] 0.245614 0.060000 0.000000
```

With respect to the Gini index, it seems like the idea is as expressed [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378437111007230):

> Gini’s index equals half the mean [symbolized as $\langle \cdot \rangle$] absolute difference between two normalized and independent population-samples $W^1$ and $W^2.$
>
> $$G = ⟨(W^1 − W^2)+⟩ =\frac 1 2 ⟨|W^1 − W^2|⟩,\tag {38}$$
>
> where $W^1$ and $W^2$ are two i.i.d. copies of the normalized random variable $\hat W.$ Eq. (38) is an explicit stochastic formula for
> Gini’s index $G$ — representing it in terms of the normalized random variable $\hat W.$